# Reading an array and displaying the outcome using a look up table in C

Tags: c

So far I have this code, I have been told that I am reading the switches on porth rather than reading the array ( scanner ) as I should be.

The initial problem is this: [image: original problem]

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    /******************* Declare the port addresses **********************/
    unsigned char *DDRA  = (unsigned char *)0x0002;
    unsigned char *PORTB = (unsigned char *)0x0001;
    unsigned char *DDRB  = (unsigned char *)0x0003;
    unsigned char *PTH   = (unsigned char *)0x0260;
    unsigned char *DDRH  = (unsigned char *)0x0262;
    unsigned char *PERH  = (unsigned char *)0x0264;

    /******************* Declare functions*******************************/
    unsigned char threshold;
    unsigned char read;
    unsigned char index;
    /************************** Scanner Data ******************************/

    unsigned char scanner[255] =  { 50,
                                     4,   9,  14,  18,  23,  26,  29,  30,  31,  32,
                                    34,  37,  41,  47,  54,  63,  71,  80,  87,  92,
                                    94,  94,  92,  89,  85,  83,  83,  86,  93, 102,
                                   115, 128, 141, 153, 161, 164, 164, 160, 152, 144,
                                   137, 132, 132, 136, 146, 161, 178, 196, 213, 226
                                  };

    /******************* Set up I/O ports ********************************/
    *DDRH = 0x00;                   /* make Port H an input port */
    *PERH = 0xFF;                   /* enable Port H */
    *DDRA = 0xFF;                   /* make Port A an output port */
    *DDRB = 0xFF;                   /* make Port B an output port */

    /******************* Main loop ***************************************/

    *PORTB = 255; // This clears the display on PORTB //
    threshold = *PTH; // Make PORTH equal to threshold //
    read = scanner[0];
    index = 1;

    do {
        *PORTB = pattern(scanner[index]/32);
        wait (1);
    } while ((index<=scanner[0]) && (read<threshold));

    if (index < threshold) {
        printf("threshold reached at reading %d with a current value %d.", index, scanner[index]);
    } else {
        printf("Threshold not reached after %d readings.", scanner[255]);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
/******************* Pattern Function **********************************/

void pattern(char threshold) {
    unsigned char LedTable [8] = {0b00000001,
                                  0b00000011,
                                  0b00000111,
                                  0b00001111,
                                  0b00011111,
                                  0b00111111,
                                  0b01111111,
                                  0b11111111
                                 };
    unsigned char index;
    unsigned char display;
    unsigned char sw_on;
    unsigned char sw_off;

    index = threshold;
    sw_on = ((unsigned char)LedTable[index]);
    sw_off = threshold & 0b11111111;

    if (sw_off & 0b00010000) {
        display = sw_on | 0b10000000 ;
    } else {
        display = sw_on & 0b01111111;
    }
}

/********************** Wait Function **********************************/

void wait(int seconds) {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int k;

    for (k = 0; k <= seconds; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= 2000; j++);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to run this on a simulator but don't have the correct software to convert the code into an s19 file to run it correctly, I cannot download it as I am currently at work for the next week. However I have used QT to clear all errors.

Comment: `index = 1;` `do { ... } (index<=scanner[0] ..);` will always test true as you are never incrementing `index`. (there may be other issues, but that is a showstopper)

Comment: ok so how do I go about doing this whilst retaining the divide by 32 in the do while loop?

Comment: Were you able to accomplish your assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question wasn't clear, I think I've got it...

**Notes**:

- I assume that `scanner` contains dummy data and is used to mock the device.
- I am using *VStudio 10* (on 64bit *Win10*), so certain things in your code won't work:

  - The binary formatted numbers (e.g. *0b00000001*), so I had to convert them (to hex).
  - Some assignments (e.g. `unsigned char *DDRA  = (unsigned char *)0x0002;` which is trying to dereference the 2nd memory byte, and that's not allowed).
- However, I've also found some issues that no compiler would like:

  1. The assignment: `*PORTB = pattern(scanner[index]/32);`, while `pattern` returns nothing: `void pattern(char threshold)`.
  2. Referencing `pattern` and `wait` from `main`, when they haven't been declared.

So, I have 2 questions:

- Does the code even compile?
- What compiler are you using?

As I said that I had to modify the code to compile on my environment (especially the binary number problems), I'm not going to post the whole code snippet that would do the trick, but instruct what portions of the existing code (**in the question code snippet**, so you would have to update the code on your machine/device with what's in your question) to replace with what.

- For problem *1.* (that I mentioned above): the function should return an `unsigned char`:

  - The function definition: `void pattern(char threshold)` should be changed to `unsigned char pattern(char threshold)`.
  - You have to return something from it (I assume it's `display`), so add `return display;` before the function closing brace (`}`).
- For problem *2.*, either:

  - Forward declare (add the 2 lines of code below) `wait` and `pattern` **before** `main`'s declaration (`int main(void) {`):

    `void wait(int seconds);`
    `unsigned char pattern(char threshold);`
  - Move `wait` and `pattern` function bodies before `main`.
- A 3rd  (minor, I suppose typo) problem that I fixed when I edited the question was that the 4th `LedTable` element was missing the `0b` marker at the beginning.

Now, the logical problem (and some others) relies in the `do/while` loop (as you said - or better: as you were told). So, I suggest to replace that loop:

```
do {
    *PORTB = pattern(scanner[index]/32);
    wait (1);
} while ((index<=scanner[0]) && (read<threshold));
```

by:

```
while (((index <= read) && (scanner[index] < threshold))) {
    *PORTB = pattern(scanner[index] / 32);
    //printf("pattern(scanner[%d]/32): %02X - %d\n", index, pattern(scanner[index] / 32), scanner[index]);
    wait(1);
    index++;
};
```

Explanation:

- by changing the `do/while` into `while` loop, I am avoiding some corner cases that might arise involving either the 1st or the last element in the array.
- `index++;` - that's the error that @DavidC.Rankin spotted: if you don't increment `index` it will have the same value (that you assign to it before entering the loop), and the loop will never end.
- the loop conditions(I'm going to go over them from right to left in the original code):

  - compare `threshold` to `read` or the array index makes no sense.
  - compare `index` to `read` instead of `scanner[0]` - **this is optional** the 2 have the same value, I chose this form because it's more efficient.

The last change is: replace `if (index < threshold) {` by `if (index < read) {` as it makes no point comparing an array index (after exiting the `while` loop) to a value (that might be in that array) - same thing as above.

Answer (score 0):

While almost all of what CristiFati wrote is right, there's a small error in:

> The last change is: replace `if (index < threshold) {` by `if (index < read) {` …

Since the previous loop runs `while (((index <= read) …` and `scanner[read]` is a valid data point, it's

```
    if (index <= read)
    {
```

One more thing:

```
        printf("Threshold not reached after %d readings.", scanner[255]);
```

has to be

```
        printf("Threshold not reached after %d readings.", scanner[0]);
```

- after all, `scanner[255]` would be out of the array bounds.